# Suslin measurable sets and the smallest field containing all analytic sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

Let $X$ be a Polish space. Recall that the [Suslin operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin_operation) is the operation $\mathcal{A}$ such that for any *Suslin scheme* $\{A_s : s \in \omega^{<\omega}\}$ of subsets of $X$, we have:
$$
\mathcal{A}\{A_s : s \in \omega^{<\omega}\} := \bigcup_{a \in \omega^\omega} \bigcap_{n<\omega} A_{a\upharpoonright n}
$$
The $\sigma$-algebra of *Suslin measurable* $\mathcal{S}$ subsets of $X$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra, containing all open subsets of $X$, such that $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under the Suslin operation. Since every analytic set is the application of the Suslin operation to a Suslin scheme of closed subsets of $X$, $\mathcal{S}$ contains all analytic subsets of $X$.

Is $\mathcal{S}$ exactly the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all analytic subsets of $X$?

Comment: Do you mean "$\sigma$-field", or "field"? In any event, my comments to the mathoverflow questions [Universally measurable but not analytically measurable set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/396694/15780) and [A Baire subset of reals that is not Suslin measurable](https://mathoverflow.net/q/412137/15780) about the $\sigma(\Sigma_1^1)$ sets ($\sigma$-algebra generated by the analytic/Suslin sets) and $C$-sets (an $\omega_1$-length hierarchy of collections of sets in obtaining a collection closed under the operations of forming a $\sigma$-algebra and applying the Suslin operation) may be of interest.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I meant $\sigma$-field. Thanks for the references.